# How can I test a managed item many times in Android in-app?

Tags: android

I know that a managed item only can be ordered one time per use, I'm testing my app, so I need to buy the managed item many times for test purpose.

I hope to find a simply way, so I login to https://wallet.google.com/ to cancel the order. but when I try to order the managed item again, I still get an error information: I can't buy the managed item repeated.

How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: You must consume the item, consume all the pendant items before new tests http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume

Comment: Is there a simple way?

Comment: Without your code I don't know it. But if you get an error buying an item first consume the item and then try it again. It worked on my dirty code.

Comment: I think it's too complex o use "consume", can I delete the order record on Google Play?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Is there a solution?